# About paging and moving circularly from one page to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paging

In my application am using paging concept with 4 pages along with UIScrollView.
Its working fine but 
my problem is
**1.**
I want to show 2nd page(some part) in 1st page ending,
                3rd page(some part) in 2nd page ending,
         and    4th page(some part) in 3rd page ending.

**2.**
Now i can move from 1st to 2nd , 2nd to 3rd, 3rd to 4th page again if want to move to 1st page means i have to go pages like 4-3-2-1
but i want to move pages circularly like 1-2-3-4-1-2-3-..... like that

Example code

```
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++)
{
    [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
self.viewControllers = controllers;


// a page is the width of the scroll view
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, 1);
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;

pageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;

// pages are created on demand
// load the visible page
// load the page on either side to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];
```

}

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
if (page < 0) return;
if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

// replace the placeholder if necessary
WhatsNewViewConroller *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
    controller = [[WhatsNewViewConroller alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    controller.delegateController = self;
}

// add the controller's view to the scroll view
if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
// We don't want a "feedback loop" between the UIPageControl and the scroll delegate in
// which a scroll event generated from the user hitting the page control triggers updates from
// the delegate method. We use a boolean to disable the delegate logic when the page control is used.
if (pageControlUsed) {
    // do nothing - the scroll was initiated from the page control, not the user dragging
    return;
}

// Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
pageControl.currentPage = page;

// load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];

// A possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible
```

}

Here am changing page

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
int page = pageControl.currentPage;

// load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];

// update the scroll view to the appropriate page
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

// Set the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl. See scrollViewDidScroll: above.
pageControlUsed = YES;
```

}

Any one can help or suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put some code here.You will get solution quickly. Without code we can just guide you not able to solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading new page, instead of using page-1, page and page+1; use (page -1)%4 , page%4 and (page+1)%4

Comment: I just got what you mean exactly. What you can do is add two view at page -1 and 5. At page -1 load page 4 and at page 5 load page 1. Finally declare method name scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation and see if you are in page -1 move scroll view without animation to page 4 and for 5 move to 1.